# OpenGL: Nothing drawn

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, codeblocks, microsoft-glee

Graphics: **AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series**

Running: **Windows 7(64 bit)**

Program: **CodeBlocks(32 bit)**

OpenGL Library: **GLee**

*This is where I setup the window. Its an SDL window using OpenGL rendering.*

```
void Init(int w, int h, bool fullScr)
{
    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0 ) {
    printf("Unable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    winW = w*scale;
    winH = h*scale;
    original_winW = w;
    origianl_winH = h;

    putenv("SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS");
    putenv("SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED=1");

    getenv("SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS");
    getenv("SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED");

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 ); // *new*
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_SWAP_CONTROL, 0 ); // *new*

    //Sets up the screen and displays the window
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( winW, winH, 32, SDL_OPENGL | (fullScr*SDL_FULLSCREEN)  ); // *changed*
    screenRect.x = 0;
    screenRect.y = 0;
    screenRect.w = winW;
    screenRect.h = winH;

    SDL_ShowCursor(false);

    SetGLState();
}
```

*This is the SetGLState() mentioned above.*

```
void SetGLState(){
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D ); //Enable 2d texturing

    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); //Set clear color (rgba)

    glViewport( 0, 0, winW, winH ); //Set the viewport

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); //Clear back buffer?

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION ); //Set to projection
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(0.0f, winW, winH, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); //Create orthogonal projection matrix

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW ); //Set back to model view
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

*This is where the images are drawn to the screen*

```
void DrawImage(GLSurface image, float x, float y)
{
    // Bind the texture to which subsequent calls refer to
    if(boundTexture != image.Surface){glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, image.Surface ); boundTexture = image.Surface; }

    glReadPixels(x,y,image.w*2,image.h*2,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL,NULL);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(scale,scale,1);

    glRotatef(image.rotation[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(image.rotation[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(image.rotation[2], 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    if(scale == 7.5)x += 48;

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        //Bottom-left vertex (corner)
        glColor3b(127,127,127);
        glTexCoord2i( 0, 0 ); //Position on texture to begin interpolation
        glVertex3f( x, y, 0.f ); //Vertex Coords

        //Bottom-right vertex (corner)
        glTexCoord2i( 1, 0 );
        glVertex3f( x+image.w, y, 0.f );

        //Top-right vertex (corner)
        glTexCoord2i( 1, 1 );
        glVertex3f( x+image.w, y+image.h, 0.f );

        //Top-left vertex (corner)
        glTexCoord2i( 0, 1 );
        glVertex3f( x, y+image.h, 0.f );
    glEnd();
}
```

This window doesn't draw anything, and I can't figure out why. I haven't looked at this code in awhile, but I know that on a previous install of windows, I had it working. All of my other projects run, but this one doesn't. It just renders a blank screen. The weird thing is--I have a resize function for this window. When that function gets called, the screen displays a *white* screen instead of a black one.

Edit**
*This code is called at the end once everything has been drawn to the screen. It was already included in my code.*

```
void Flip(){
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the state set in SetGLState is drawing state. Call it from the DrawImage function. Most importantly, glClear *must* be put in the draw function, it doesn't make sense anywhere else.

That call to `glReadPixels` makes no sense.

And you must swap the buffers when done `SDL_SwapBuffers` (IIRC, haven't used SDL in some time).

Comment: I just edited my post. Everything you told me to do was already done, just in a separate function. I forgot to include it. There should be no other code missing from my post now, sorry. The problem still remains.

Comment: @user1959403: You should put glClear not after the buffer swap call. It looks weird and may confuse. You normally always clear at the begin of drawing a frame.

Comment: I still haven't figured this problem out--even after fixing all of your suggestions. Is there something not code related that could be the problem?

Comment: @user1959403: Seeing only the code snippets you posted I'm out of ideas. I need to see the full program to make any other suggestions. I suggest you put it on pastebin.com or into a github gist.